# activate breakpoint while dragging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, breakpoints, react-grid-layout

I am trying to debug flickering of the drop placeholder while dragging over the droppable area. I want to activate the breakpoint when the flickering occurs so that I can identify which part of the code is responsible for this.

Here is what I have tried,

- added `debugger` command to suspected places in the code but the breakpoint does not activates while flickering.
- added event listener breakpoints but since I have to keep the mousedown, pause prior to flickering breaks the flow.
- added a breakpoint using a setTimeout, the breakpoint activates while flickering but the call stack only contains setTimeout and its callback.

How can I activate a breakpoint in the case?

[image]

Comment: An idea: https://css-tricks.com/set-timed-debugger-web-inspect-hard-grab-elements/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The call stack only contains the callback function and the setTimeout function. Is there a way to log the functions called by the javascript while the user is dragging?

Answer (score 0):

By reading some articles it seems like that for some people breakpoints don't activate while debugging if you are running Vscode as an administrator. Try disabling the "Run as an administration" if you are using Visual Studio Code.